# Firefox firing the 'pause' event on videos when the time is changed or it ends

Tags: html, events, firefox, video

I have a video embedded on a website and I'm getting some odd behavior in Firefox.

Every time I change the playback position by clicking on the time slider, the `pause` event is fired. Similarly, every time the video ends the `pause` event is fired, even before the `ended` event.

I was first wondering if I had an error in some JS I had written (to make the video bigger on playback, and then shrink it on pause - [code here](http://pastebin.com/9Mw31sEp)). However, I tested with just this simple code and the behavior still exists -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    video = $('#intro-video');
    
    video.on('pause', function(){
        alert('pause');
    });
    
});
```

This doesn't happen in other browsers, and it is very undesirable behavior for Firefox. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Thanks,

## Note

If anyone is interested, here is the link to [Pastebin containing my code](http://pastebin.com/9Mw31sEp), but after testing with the above I'm pretty sure this is not the issue.

## Update

I have found [this thread](http://www.sitepoint.com/essential-audio-and-video-events-for-html5/) which suggests the behavior described about is actually by design, but I find that hard to believe. The author says that IE, Opera and Safari get it wrong while Firefox gets it right, but surely that's not correct...

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on monitoring events for HTML5 video/audio and from time to time I find something that you described: it is not consistent across browsers and given the same browser it can vary between versions. I would suggest you stick to the specs in this case:

- [ended event](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#ended-playback): it should fire a pause event right before the ended event (given you have no current media controller ie multiple sync media players). Here Firefox does it as expected.
- [seeking](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#dom-media-seeking): it should not fire a pause event. There is no mention of that in the specs. Here Firefox seems to drop the ball. However if the video is paused in FF and you seek then the pause event is not fired.

Amongst IE 11, FF 28 and Chrome 34 I found that only Chrome does fit the specs to the letter for this question on both events.

You could consider asking Mozilla why is such a behavior implemented?

If you want to bypass this behavior (do not know how to call it) you need to build you own custom controls in JS. The code below illustrates that the pause event does not fire if you programmatically seek to a point in time of the video (the #seekBar div):

```
<video id="intro-video" width="640" height="360" controls>
<source src="../media/360p.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
</video>
<div id="seekBar">Seek +5sec</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
video = $('#intro-video');
videoJ = $('#intro-video')[0];

video.on('pause', function(){
    console.log('pause');
});
 video.on('play', function(){
    console.log('play');
});
video.on('ended', function(event){
    console.log('ended');
});
video.on('seeking', function(){
    console.log('seeking');
});
video.on('seeked', function(){
    console.log('seeked');
});
$('#seekBar').on('click',function(){
var currentT = videoJ.currentTime;
videoJ.currentTime = currentT + 5;//on click seek forward + 5 sec
});
});
</script>
```

You can have a look here to start building your own [controls](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/custom-html5-video-player-with-css3-and-jquery/).

Maybe a lib like [videojs](http://www.videojs.com/) can fix it for you (not tested on this chain of events)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue on Firefox by adding a timeout and checking if the video is paused inside the timeout. Only when the `video.paused` returns true, I execute my code:

```js
const showOverlay = video => video.closest('.jsvideo').classList.remove('is--playing');

$$('.js-video video', video => {
    video.addEventListener('pause', () => {
        if (video.readyState !== 4) {
            return true;
        }

        // Firefox dispatches the pause event but 
        // doesn't set the video to paused 
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (video.paused) {
                showOverlay();
            }
        }, 250);
    });

    video.addEventListener('ended', showOverlay);
});
```

The `$$` functions is just a helper function which queries the DOM.

I used a 250ms timeout but I think it can be significantly reduced (even to zero) because the check will be executed after the `pause` event is triggered.

The actual UX is left untouched because the timeout is unnoticeable and doesn't affect the speed of the UI updates.