# Javascript: html5 video pauses after seeking

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari

I found it is an old issue but how are the deals with it now? The video pauses after seeking on desktop in Safari browser (not in Chrome ) when you seek in unbuffered zone. On mobiles all is ok.

What is the best decision to fix it? Manually get pause state on waiting/suspend/canplay/stalled state and then set it on the "seeked" state? It didn't helps properly for me.

```
var wasPaused = player.paused;

player.addEventListener('waiting', onwaiting); //waiting/suspend/canplay/stalled 
player.addEventListener('seeked', onSeeked);

        function onwaiting() {
            console.log("onwaiting", player.paused);
            wasPaused = player.paused;
        }

        function onSeeked() {
            if (wasPaused === false)
                player.play();
        }
```

Comment: Not a programming question. Ask at **https://superuser.com**.

Comment: Sure? Why then there is a lot of Javascript code in the same question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046652/firefox-firing-the-pause-event-on-videos-when-the-time-is-changed-or-it-ends

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Your question [**did not have any code**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46095009/revisions) three hours ago... it was only asking about browser usage. Now it's better for StackOveflow.

Comment: Tell me, how can you perform "Manually get pause state on waiting/suspend/canplay/stalled state and then set it on the "seeked" state" without a code?